# Java simple arrays structure in memory

Tags: java, arrays, object, memory

How Java stores objects like int[] in memory, what is they structure?

Not complex compound types like ArrayList - the question is not about them.
I want to know exactly about arrays of primitive types like a int[].

Can't find any detailed information on this, other than that these are just chunks of memory.
Although there is a whole structure - pointers and so on ...

Thanks a lot,

Gudot

Comment: That's going to depend on the particular implementation.  The most common is probably a C style pointer with some metadata (like size), but that shouldn't matter to anyone writing a program in Java- those kind of details aren't exposed in any way.

Comment: Thanks. My question for in-depth understanding and study of details.

Comment: The [hotspot source code is on GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot). If you want to know implementation details - and this goes for anything, not just the JVM - then you should be prepared for the fact that you might have to go and look yourself. There is a good reason that low-level implementation details aren't well-documented and that's because they quickly become outdated. As a rule of thumb, if you don't know where to begin looking for an implementation detail, you probably don't have a good enough reason to not know or care about it.

Answer (score 1):

The general structure of an array is like this:

[image]

And here you have a great explanation from a great source; [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
Its a great -begginer friendly- tutorial ;)